# I cannot download anything ie. msn or pokerstarsAny ideas?

Tags: downloads

When I try to download anything it says;

> An error occurred when loading the archive
>
> Archive: /tmp/wlsetup-web-2.exe [/tmp/wlsetup-web-2.exe]
>   End-of-central-directory signature not found.
>
> Either this file is not a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a
>   multi-part archive. In the latter case the central directory and
>   zipfile comment will be found on the last disk(s) of this archive.
>
> zipinfo: cannot find zipfile directory in one of
>   /tmp/wlsetup-web-2.exe or /tmp/wlsetup-web-2.exe.zip, and cannot find
>   /tmp/wlsetup-web-2.exe.ZIP, period.

Comment: Are you using WINE to run Windows apps?

Answer (score 2):

The only good way to install software into ubuntu is to use the package manager (it should be named Software center in English, and show as an icon in the left bar of the standard ubuntu interface). You should be able to find there some applications suiting your needs, or maybe they are already installed on your system. For example, the instant messenger client Empathy, which is included in ubuntu install, is able to communicate over MSN / WLM protocols without any problem.

If you really want to use windows applications, you should download the windows emulator Wine (through Software center !) and then choose Wine as default application to open windows executables. But this option isn't encouraged except for specific software who don't have any open equivalent, because you would then face the same issues as the ones you may have with windows : the need to be careful about virus, the need to solve dependencies by hand, the frequent compatibility issues or clashes...

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Ubuntu!

As others have said, Ubuntu is not Windows and their software is not compatible. You will need to install Ubuntu/Linux specific software. You can browse the Ubuntu Software Center for most all software you would ever want or need. It is similar to an app store, like for Android or iPhones, except that it is almost all free! Not all software is cross-platform (meaning they have versions for Linux/Windows/Mac), so you may have to use an alternative for some of your favorite programs. To use MSN, Ubuntu comes with a built-in instant messenger client called Empathy.

If you are having issues finding the software you need, here is a great site to find alternative native Linux software: http://alternativeto.net/software/?platform=linux

There is no native PokerStars client for Ubuntu, but as others have said, you can run it through Wine. Here is some more information on how to get it installed with Wine: http://www.thepokerbank.com/rooms/pokerstars/ubuntu/ Although Wine is a great piece of software and allows you to run some Windows native applications on Ubuntu, it should always be treated as  a last resort. Some programs may not run well or have too many Windows dependencies.

Comment: Thanks guys, admittedly I'm struggling to get used to ubuntu, however Im already seeing the vast improvement from windows. I have been have a little play around and had already managed to find wine and have almost sorted out pokerstars as this is an essential for me ;) lol. Thanks for the tips I shall make sure Im careful when using wine then and will definately download Empathy instead of MSN. Cheers peeps. x